# How to know which w3wp process is for the intranet appication I am looking for

Tags: iis-7, windbg, crash-dumps

I have to take memory dump of IIS process for investigating an issue via Windbg. I basically have four intranet applications that run on same IIS server. This mean that I see four w3wp process. Is there someway of finding which process is tied to which IIS application? I know I can use Process Explorer from sysinternals that show various threads and even their call stacks, however, all my intranet applications uses common libraries and sometime stack could be very similar. Wondering if there is any better way of figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the application pool is passed as a command line parameter to w3wp.exe.

```
w3wp.exe -ap "MyApplicationPoolName" ... [the rest of command line]
```

I usually just use Windows Task Manager, it can display command line for processes if you configure it to display this column in View menu. Alternatively, `tlist.exe` from the debugger package can do that too:

```
tlist w3wp.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

May be 'appcmd list apps' will do the trick.
Refer to http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/